# Why are my div elements not centering on the page and just lining up?

Tags: html, css, alignment

This code makes the divs all line up, but they don't align in the center of the page. I've looked at tons of other posts about this and none of them seem to work for me.

HTML:

```
<div class="both">

    <div class="contain">

    <div class="left-large-image"></div>

</div>

<div class="contain">


<div class="middle-large-image"></div>

</div>
<div class="contain">


<div class="right-large-image"></div>

</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
        .left-large-image{
width:26rem;
height:20rem;
margin:1rem;
margin-bottom:0;
background-size:cover;
background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/xqrZzD6/pla.jpg");};

.middle-large-image{
width:26rem;
display:block;
height:20rem;
margin:1rem;
margin-bottom:0;
background-size:cover;
background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/6HfCtBm/messi.jpg");};

        .right-large-image{
width:26rem;
display:block;
height:20rem;
margin:1rem;
margin-bottom:0;
background-size:cover;
background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/vP723BQ/zlatan.jpg");};

    .contain{
float:left;
display:inline-block;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
vertical-align: middle;}
```

Maybe the left float has something to do with it?

Comment: Please clear your code (its hard to read due to singlelines) and provide fiddle. It will help others to help you.

Comment: Please add code snippet it will be easy to answer your question.